# How do I change the favicon in the Modern UI in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

My current scenario - Classic view shows favicon which I have changed in my custom master page which is my brand logo which is working fine. but if I exit classic view it change the favicon to SharePoint default favicon

Answer (score 0):

**You can refer below link:**

https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/08/24/change-favicon-on-modern-sharepoint-sites/

Regards,
Chandani Prajapati